# Execute custom functions one after another - Callback logic in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

There is a form which submits some data to an API in my component. Assume that it's method is `ProcessLogin()`. Inside this function I have written my API calls using axios. With the help of `then()` I have handled my server response and displayed my toast. All good.

Now as a part of my code clean up, I have decided to move all my axios functions to another `api.js` file and export functions from there. Here is an example function I have in my `api.js` file :

```
function ApiLogin(data) {
const url   = `${BASE_URL}/authenticate`;
axios.post(url,data).then(response => {
  return response;
}).catch(error => {
  return error.response;
});
}
```

On the other side in my component I have my method defined as below :

```
methods: {
    ProcessLogin() {
    var status = ApiLogin(this.data);
    console.log(status);
 }
}
```

When executing this, I get undefined on my console. I know why it is happening. Because console.log(status) executes before ApiLogin could process and sends it's response. How to handle this kind of situation.? I know that callback is the rescue here, but I am not really sure about how to integrate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return the **axios** call from your **ApiLogin** function:

```
function ApiLogin(data) {
  const url = `${BASE_URL}/authenticate`
  return axios.post(url, data)
}
```

You could then handle the response in your component using ***then*** and console log from there:

```
methods: {
  ProcessLogin() {
    ApiLogin(this.data)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

...or with ***async/await***:

```
methods: {
  ProcessLogin: async function() {
    try {
      var status = await ApiLogin(this.data)
      console.log(status)
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad this helped you out.